# How to transform data in php

Tags: php

i have a variable `00 EF 5D 0E` and i would want to write a function which transforms any variable of this sort in the following manner.

1) Spaces removed and replaced with colons.

2)all letters reduced to lower case

3)if 0 is the first on a pair, it must be removed i.e

```
00 EF 5D 0E becomes 0:ef:5d:e
88 8E 07 TT becomes 88:8e:7:tt
```

Is possible to write a php function which can achieve this or i have to extract it to a file and then use tool such as sed

Comment: yes this is possible, did you tried anything?

Comment: Takes hardly 3 lines of code, try it

Comment: let me try out a function, i have been using Sed so i totally had no idea in PHP as i am a new user

Comment: Make your own kind of music: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: Have you even checked PHP's string functions? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: @itachi yes as separator,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input and expected output, you could do something like this. Note that dynamic functions require 5.3+.

```
// split input by spaces
$parts = explode(' ', $input);

// remove leading zeros
$parts = array_map(function($part) {
    return preg_replace('/0/', '', $part, 1);
}, $parts);

// make lowercase and join parts with ":"
$output = strtolower(implode(':', $parts));

echo $output;
```

[**Sandbox Test**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cf5fbe90afb8ecf9e1a493e2f3a3e51fc116f64)